How to solve this system of algebraic equations?
I was solving a Physics Problem and after going on solving I arrived at these equations
$$(D_1u+1)\left[{D_2}\cdot\dfrac{(D_1-L)u+1}u+1\right] =\dfrac 1{M_1} $$
$$(D_2u+1)\left[{D_1}\cdot\dfrac{(D_2-L)u+1}u+1\right] =\dfrac 1{M_2}$$
Where $|u|\gt |\dfrac1{D_1}|,|\dfrac1{D_2}|$ and $|\dfrac{(D_1-L)u+1}u|,|\dfrac{(D_2-L)u+1}u|>|\dfrac1{D_1}|,|\dfrac1{D_2}|$
I have to find $\Delta D=D_1-D_2$ where$ D_1$ and $D_2$ are in diopter$(\mathrm m^{-1});$ $M_1=1; M_2=4; L= 25\mathrm{cm}$
Here calculation is coming very messy although equatios are similar-looking. Is there any easier way to solve this like using concept of symmetry or anything else.Please Help
For reference the original problem is(for someone who wants to check my calculations at the end step of this question below)

What is the numerical value of $u$ ?

@JJacquelin I had pasted the original problem. $u$ is the object distance in the lens formula.
